# Get a specific post with the loop to fill out specific areas of site

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to use the loop in order to query a specific post and display that posts content, title and custom fields on my page?

i was thinking something like:

```
if (have_posts() && the_post().id == 66) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use `query_posts()` where p = the post_id (1)

```
<?php query_posts('p=1'); ?> 
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <?php the_title(); ?>
     <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: so if i wanted to display the post with ID 66 it should look like this ('p=66') ?